# Hide or Show div based on input field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide a div based on the input value. From the database, I generate many documents, I have a hidden input field with `id=form_type`  which can have 2 different values: `typeA` and `typeB`. Documents that are displayed some have value typeA and some value typeB.

In my case if `input with id=form_type, class="form-type"` have value `typeA` I want to hide `div with id=hide` else if form_type have value `typeB` I don't want that div to be displayed.

I tried this code but it only takes value only for the first input with id `form_type` , for example if in first document value=typeA , it takes for all documents like that even that in other documents value can be different:

```
   var hide_fiels = $('.form-type').attr("value");           
        if (hide_fiels == "typeA"){ 
            $('#hide').css('display','none');
        }
        else{ 
            $('#hide').css('display','block');
        }
```

My html code looks something like this:

```
{% if doc_report_all.results %}
{% for doc_report in doc_report_all.results%}
    <table align="center" class="table table-striped " >
    <input type="hidden"  class="form-type" id="form_type" value="{{ doc_report.form_type }}">
    <tbody> 
    <tr> <td>  //code </td></tr>
    <tr> <td> //code </td></tr>
    <tr> <td> //code </td></tr>
    <tr> <td> //code </td></tr>
    <div id="hide" style="display: none;"> 
    <tr> <td> //code </td></tr>
    <tr> <td> //code </td></tr>
    </div>
    </body                            

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: have you alert you "hide_fiels" what you  get ?

Comment: you have that output in loop? you cant have same id used more than once

Comment: Output is 'typeA'  @ShailendraSharma

Comment: I tried using classes but still the same problem, I edited my question @Pepo_rasta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important thing is you should make use of `classes` instead of `ids` when handling multiple forms where elements would otherwise have the same `id`.
Also, you should move your `hidden input` outside of the `table` element, since this is not considered valid HTML. Point 3 is you cannot have a `div` element inside a `tbody` element. Only `tr` is allowed.

To make things easier you can wrap the whole table and hidden input inside a wrapper `div` for easier looping.

Then your HTML should look something like this:

```
{% if doc_report_all.results %}
{% for doc_report in doc_report_all.results%}
<div class="form">
    <input type="hidden" class="form_type" value="{{ doc_report.form_type }}">
    <table align="center" class="table table-striped " >
        <tbody> 
            <tr> <td> </td></tr>
            <tr> <td> </td></tr>
            <tr> <td> </td></tr>
            <tr> <td> </td></tr>
            <tr class="toggle" style="display: none;"> <td> </td></tr>
            <tr class="toggle" style="display: none;"> <td> </td></tr>
            <tr class="toggle" style="display: none;"> <td> </td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

And your JavaScript could be like this:

```
$(".form").each(function()
{
    if ($(this).find(".form_type").val() == "typeA")
        $(this).find(".toggle").hide();
    else
        $(this).find(".toggle").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can’t have multiple elements with the same id.

See spec: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Comment: I tried using classes but still the same problem, I edited my question.

Comment: I think @ZiNNED answer is what you are looking for. You need to scope the selection of the input value and the element you want to hide.